# Recovering a Trello account when you forgot which email was used to create it

Tags: trello, account-management

I have used Trello for some time. There is lots of important information in the account.

I can't remember which email I used for registration. I checked all my mailboxes but can't find any clues.

I can just remember my username. I also have the information of all my boards.
I also invited a friend to some boards, but he can only sees my name, not the email address I used.

What can I do? I really need this account.

Comment: The best solution would be to contact Trello support directly with the information you have to prove to them that you own the account. They might then tell you the e-mail address you used.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Trello help pages](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/993610-recovering-your-trello-account):

> **Verifying your account**
>
> We have only two ways to verify that you are the owner of your
>   account:
>
> 1. You know the email (or username) and password of your account and can log in at trello.com.
> 2. You own the email address associated with your account and can recover your password at https://trello.com/forgot.
>
> NOTE: If your account was created via Google log-in, you will also be
>   able to recover your Trello account by logging in via your Google
>   account.
>
> Because these are the only two methods to verify your account, it is
>   critically important that you keep your email address up to date. If
>   you change jobs, graduate from college, etc. and no longer have access
>   to the original email address you used to access Trello, you may not
>   be able to recover your account if you forget your password.
>
> **You don't use that email anymore**
>
> You may no longer have access to the email address associated with
>   your account. This happens sometimes when you change jobs and aren't
>   using your work email anymore. This can also happen if you delete your
>   email account.
>
> For security reasons, we are not able to change the email address on
>   your account (see below). Your best bet is to contact your former
>   employer directly and ask if they can help you reclaim your Trello
>   account by temporarily re-opening your old email account.
>
> **Why can't you change my email address?**
>
> For security reasons, we cannot change the email address associated
>   with your account. If we were allowed to change your email address,
>   this would expose your account to "social hacking." Social hacking is
>   when someone pretending to be you sends us an email asking us to
>   change the email address associated with your account, thus giving the
>   hacker control your account.
>
> For example, let's say your name is Robert Jones and your work email
>   is robert.jones@example.com. Someone could great a fake email address,
>   e.g. rjones@example.com, and email us, pretending to be you. They
>   might say how they changed jobs and no longer use
>   robert.jones@example.com and could we please change the email for
>   them. We cannot.

Having said that if you have a handful of email addresses that it could be, then use the password reset form for each email. It will email you a reset link (providing that you did actually use one of those addresses)

If you no longer have access to the email address (or don't know what it is) then you are stuck I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your username, you can type it in the "email" field of the Trello login page to sign in (it just says email, but both work). This requires that you have set a password for your account; if you signed up with a Google account then it won't work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out!